# How to do unit testing in Xcode while including a Metal library in the project

Tags: ios, xcode, unit-testing, xcode8, metal

I have a library project (A) and a Metal library project (M). M is included into A in the "Copy files" phase. That introduces a build dependency, meaning that I can't build A for the simulator because it tries to build M first, and Metal is not supported on the simulator.

That's fine, but the problem is that A contains some unit tests, and when I try to test the project, I get this error message,

`Logic Testing Unavailable. Logic testing on iOS devices is not supported. You can only run logic tests on the Simulator.`

But I can't build for the Simulator because of the aforementioned dependency...

I read https://medium.com/the-sup-app/bare-metal-working-with-metal-and-the-simulator-70e085e3a45 -- perhaps this could help me removing the dependency of M in A for the simulator, but I'm trying to do this without Cocoapods, purely in Xcode.

Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact same thing over the weekend. Tried to be a good citizen and include unit tests in my Metal project. ;-)

The only way out of this catch-22 is to not use XCTest for writing unit tests but create a separate target that runs as an app on its own. This new target then runs the unit tests.

In the old days I used GHUnit for this but I do not know if there is a suitable replacement for it these days.

Worst case scenario you can write your own little unit testing library that runs the XCTest macros.

Comment: I've done the same. I guess it's the most sensible solution atm.

Comment: Just FYI, but I found that at least with Xcode9 one can explicitly include the .metal files into a test target and then it is easy to load and run the xctest target on device. You have to create a second empty iOS app target that will contain only the test cases, but it works: https://github.com/mdejong/MetalPrefixSum